# Validate invalid attribute in XML against the XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxparser

I want to figure out any invalid elements or attributes in an xml. I have created a XSD file from the xml using Oxygen XML Editor. Now I am trying to parse & validate the xml using the XSD but my xml parses even if I add a new attribute. Below is the code. Now even though I add JUNKATTRIBUTE to my xml, it is getting parsed.
Any suggestions?

**My Code**

```
public static boolean validatehelp(String helpData, helpReport helpReport) {

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = null;
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    spf.setValidating(true);

    FileReader fileReader = null;
    try {
         SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
         fileReader =  new FileReader("help_xsd.xsd");

         spf.setSchema(sf.newSchema(new SAXSource(new InputSource(fileReader))));
         //spf.setSchema(sf.newSchema(new Source[] {new StreamSource("help_xsd.xsd")}));



        parser = spf.newSAXParser();

        MySAXHandler handler = new MySAXHandler(configReport); 

        parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(helpData)), handler);
        return true;
    }
```

**My xml**

```
<Help date="2020-06-24">
<product
id="en_US_SAN_15.0"
label="orange_16.0"
ProductName="orange 16.0 "
productName="orange 16.0 Pre"
productVersion="15.0"
baseUrl="http://help.stage.xyz.com/"
path="Help/en_US/"
ionId="orange_product_xyzlr"
ionCommentingAllowed="yes"
ionSiteArea="help"
ionRatingAllowed="yes"
ionRatingType="thumbs"
searchOptions="Community|xyz"
searchDefault="Community"
searchxyzRefinement="site=orange_V2_all"
="yes"
/>
<package
id="en_US_SAN_15.0_Using"
label="orange_16.0"
path="SAN/orange/15.0/Using"
description="SAN 15.0"
contextSensitivity="yes"
downloadContent="client.orange_V2_Using_en-us.zip"
downloadContentDefault="yes"
downloadPdf="orange_V4_help.pdf"
JUNKATTRIBUTE="JUNK"
/>
</Help>
```

**My XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Help">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="product"/>
        <xs:element ref="package"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="appId" />
      <xs:attribute name="date"  type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:attribute name="locale" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="pubId" />
      <xs:attribute name="version"  type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="product">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="baseUrl" type="xs:anyURI"/>
      <xs:attribute name="helpServiceUrl" type="xs:anyURI"/>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ionCommentingAllowed"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ionId"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ionRatingAllowed"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ionRatingType"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ionSiteArea"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="label" />
      <xs:attribute name="multidomain"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="path" />
      <xs:attribute name="productName"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="productVersion"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="searchxyzRefinement" />
      <xs:attribute name="searchBlueprintRefinement"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="searchCommunityRefinement"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="searchDefault"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="searchOptions" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="package">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="alias" />
      <xs:attribute name="baseUrl"  type="xs:anyURI"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextSensitivity"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="deprecated"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="description" />
      <xs:attribute name="downloadContent" />
      <xs:attribute name="downloadContentDefault"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="downloadPdf"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="helpmapPath"  type="xs:anyURI"/>
      <xs:attribute name="id"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="label" />
      <xs:attribute name="packageGenerator"  type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="path" />
      <xs:attribute name="urlParams" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It sounds to me as if your expectation is to NOT have the XML successfully parsed if it is not XML Schema valid; in other words, the parse()  should throw an exception if XML is not valid; correct?

Answer (score 1):

An XML file is valid if:

- It is well formed
- It conforms to any defined schema types associated with it.

In your case the xml document is well formed, and there is no schema associated with it. So therefore it is valid.

If you want to associate the xml with you defined types you need to use a namespace.

Your schema declaration:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="myNamespaceHere" xmlns="myNamespaceHere">
...
</xs:schema>
```

Your xml instance:

```
<Help date="2020-06-24" xmlns="myNamespaceHere">
...
</Help>
```

Now when you validate it your parser will know to validate against the XSD.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by Petru in the comments, this validity is not correct from a *XSD validity* point of view. The namespace is not actually required for validation to take place, but in the case when a namespace is not required the schema attribute `elementFormDefault` should be set to "unqualified" to indicate the types in the schema can be referenced without namespace qualification.

However, XSD parsers commonly ignore schema instances without namespaces which is why from a parser perspective a non-namespaced xml instance always returns as "valid" (as long as it's well formed).

Comment: I kind of agree with you but if the OP tries again with the namespace qualified schema and schema instance they will find that the parser now validates the XML against the schema, which was the original problem the OP was facing.

Comment: Thank you for considering my first comment. I'll remove it shortly, to keep your answer clean. However, please consider that without a target namespace for the schema (as you can see in the generated XSD) the elementFormDefault's value in this context is rather irrelevant. So I am inclined to believe that isn't the issue here, but rather one of expectations: parsing (well formedness) vs. validation. Most XML APIs I know, parsing with validation turned will always succeed, since validation errors are "observed" outside XML parsing (well formedness).

Comment: Thanks Hugh. I do not have control over xml. Now, I have found the problem. I was not catching the error properly and also setting Validation = false helped.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, your XML should be getting validated against the schema provided, however since you didn't include a definition for `MySAXHandler` it is difficult to know whether you're *handling* the errors when they occur.

Except for fatal errors, other validation errors will be reported by calling the `DefaultHandler.error()` method with a `SAXParseException`. If you want to handle validation errors, you'll need to implement that method. Something like:

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXParseException {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

With this handler definition (along with the rest of your code) you should see `parse` throw `SAXParseException` validation exceptions when they occur.

More information on the `ErrorHandler` interface see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html